# Simple command Javascript (window.close())

Tags: javascript

How to assure the closing of the window in the Firefox with `window.close` command?

Comment: I don't get your your problem. Just call window.close(); Of course this only works on windows, that your application has opened.

Answer (score 4):

> How assure the closing of the window in the firefox with window.close command?

You can't. If you try `window.close()` in a window you didn't open programmatically, the user will (fortunately!) be asked whether they really want to close the window. There's no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:window.close();">`

Even when the page is not opened by window.open, you can use this. I've tested it and it works for me.